# MySQL does not accept password not lets me reset password by skip-grants-table, unable to login

Tags: permissions, login, password, mysql, root

I terminal I have typed:

```
apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

It asked me for password and I gave it.

Next I typed:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

It prompted me for password. I am cent percent sure that I gave the correct password.

It gave me the output:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I did:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Output

```
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.


mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Output:

```
[1] 7843


mysql -u root mysql
```

Output:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

I did

```
apt remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client
```

and repeated all of the above procedures but with no success. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have been able to solve my problem.

In terminal you have to type:

```
systemctl start mysql.service
systemctl enable mysql.service
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

That's it all done